# Intermittent 502: bad gateway on nginx + shiny server

Tags: nginx, reverse-proxy, proxypass

I need to present a Shiny application (let's call it my_app) through HTTPS.

This is my setup:

- Public ip address is 1.2.3.4
- Shiny Server is listening on port 3333
- I installed nginx to proxy the connections from 443 (https) to localhost:3333
- I can successfully use the application using http://1.2.3.4:3333/my_app and https://1.2.3.4/my_app

Here is the problem: whenever I use my_app (which is resource-intensitive) and open another tab and try to reach https://1.2.3.4/my_app, I got "502 bad gateway" **BUT**, if I try to access it via http://1.2.3.4:3333/my_app, it works OK.

Any idea? Thanks

**UPDATE**

Here is the nginx server error log:

2016/11/15 17:20:30 [error] 28895#0: *414 upstream prematurely closed connection while reading response header from upstream, client: x.x.x.x, server: 1.2.3.4, request: "GET /my_app/ HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://127.0.0.1:3333/my_app/", host: "1.2.3.4"

2016/11/15 17:22:08 [error] 28895#0: *414 upstream prematurely closed connection while reading response header from upstream, client: x.x.x.x, server: 1.2.3.4, request: "GET /my_app/ HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://127.0.0.1:3333/my_app/", host: "1.2.3.4"

2016/11/15 17:25:11 [error] 28896#0: *452 upstream prematurely closed connection while reading response header from upstream, client: x.x.x.x, server: 1.2.3.4, request: "GET /my_app/ HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://127.0.0.1:3333/my_app/", host: "1.2.3.4"

2016/11/15 17:35:55 [error] 28896#0: *558 upstream prematurely closed connection while reading response header from upstream, client: x.x.x.x, server: 1.2.3.4, request: "GET /my_app/ HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://127.0.0.1:3333/my_app/", host: "1.2.3.4"

Comment: Check the nginx error log.

Comment: updated the question with the erro log from nginx

Comment: That looks like your app is having a problem, rather than the web server. You should check what it was doing.

Comment: thanks for the answer. But when I access shiny-server directly (using the 3333 port) all is fine, so should be something nginx related, I think.

Comment: Don't assume. Go look and verify that your app isn't having some sort of problem.

Comment: you were right Michael, the developers of the app said they need to make some modifications in order to handle multiple requests.